# Curve-shapped mesh edges

Tags: mesh, topology, smooth

I'd like to be able to transform the contour of a mesh with little detail, smoothing it with more vertices so that it follows a regular curve while retaining the initial vertices positions.
Here's an example:

[image: sharp edges to smooth edges contour]

Here I want to smooth the sharp angles between edges of my mesh so that they follow the blue curve while retaining the position of the selected vertices.
I've tried using the bevel tool on the vertices, but I don't get a nice regular curve with an even distribution of vertices.

Do you have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a *Subdivision Surface* (which would smooth the shape but may add too much geometry), you could select this edge loop and right click > *Subdivide*:

[image]

Then select the same edge loop and right click > *LoopTools* (you need to enable the *LoopTools* addon) > *Relax*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried this already, but when using the relax tool, the original vertices (the ones selected before doing a subdivide) change position. I would like to keep them at the exact same position and just interpolate "curved" egdes in between these original vertices